# SonarQube: ClassCastException while analysis execution

Tags: java, maven, classcastexception, sonarqube

I’m trying to execute mvn sonar:sonar on my maven-3.0.5 project. The sonar version is 4.1. The analysis cannot be executed because of a failed class cast to java.lang.String. Please take a look at the exception below.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project cb.module-retail-base: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: de.zeb.control.cfgmgnt.tools.contentbuild.utils.ApplicationContextHolderImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project cb.module-retail-base: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.InternalMojoBootstraper.executeMojo(InternalMojoBootstraper.java:111)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.InternalMojoBootstraper.start(InternalMojoBootstraper.java:69)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:142)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: de.zeb.control.cfgmgnt.tools.contentbuild.utils.ApplicationContextHolderImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.sonar.maven.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:37)
at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:175)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.InternalMojoBootstraper.executeMojo(InternalMojoBootstraper.java:106)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: de.zeb.control.cfgmgnt.tools.contentbuild.utils.ApplicationContextHolderImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.sonar.api.config.Settings.addProperties(Settings.java:322)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchSettings.init(BatchSettings.java:75)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchSettings.<init>(BatchSettings.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getMemberArguments(SingleMemberInjector.java:61)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.getMemberArguments(MethodInjector.java:100)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:112)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:631)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1033)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1025)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:173)
... 24 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the specific code that is giving this error?

Comment: The class `ApplicationContextHolderImpl` which cannot be casted to String is a simple java class. Also may be worth to know is that this class is a part of a maven plugin in the project pom. But: why does SQ want to cast it to String? Could you explain me some background of it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are great chances that your problem comes from some SonarQube property ("sonar.*") that:

- either is manually set in your POM to point to some variable which is not a String but some kind of specific object provided by a third party Maven plugin (I guess a custom plugin that you or your company may have written and that contains the `de.zeb.control.cfgmgnt.tools.contentbuild.utils.ApplicationContextHolderImpl` class)
- or is automatically set by this custom Maven plugin that does something wrong

In any case, the issue is not on SonarQube side.